# Get a List of Time Values before a (certain) Minutes from the Current time upto the Current Time in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, time

I need to define a function to get a [list] of str values of time from *"M"* minutes before the current time, up to the current time (including current time), and then check whether any of the values match the time value in the Time column of a given CSV file.

I thought of the idea for a *for loop* but could not figure out how to add and append the list for M no. of times (Quality of an Absolute Beginner). So, I adjusted with the following code which only supports **M = 1** :

```
def Time_Check_Min(M= 1):
    #Check the current system time
    timestr = datetime.now()
    Check_TIMEnow = timestr.strftime("%H:%M")

    #Add 'M' min to Current Time
    Ahead_Time = (timestr + timedelta(minutes=M))
    Check_TIME = Ahead_Time.strftime("%H:%M")

    #Check if the current time is mentioned in the Dataframe
    if Check_TIME in df_.Time.values or Check_TIMEnow in df_.Time.values:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I require the output as a list in ('%H:%M') format so as to then check if any of them is present in the CSV. For Example, Taking the current system time to be *'16:50'* and M = 3 , then the list should contain 4 elements, like :

```
['16:47', '16:48', '16:49', '16:50']
```

Also, I thought of using the *between time* method since I am using **pandas**. But again, I do not know if this would really help.

Do I need to change my approach? If Yes, then which would be the best way to do so... and if not, HOW to get that damn list?

```
                    !! Thanks for your Time for these Time_Values !!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you're using pandas we can do this with a pandas `.date_range` function and some handy list slicing.

```
from typing import Optional
import pandas as pd

def get_time_delta_range(time_value : str, M : Optional[int] = 1) -> list:
    t_range = pd.date_range(
                 '01 Jan 2020', '02 Jan 2020',freq='min')\
                 .strftime('%H:%M').tolist()

    idx = t_range.index(time_value)
    return t_range[idx -M : idx + 1]
```

---

```
vals = get_time_delta_range('16:50', M=3)
print(vals)

['16:47', '16:48', '16:49', '16:50']
```

then use `isin` to filter your list.

```
df_['Time'].isin(vals)
```

---

#### edit.

```
def get_time_delta_range(dataframe : pd.DataFrame,
                         time_value : str, M : Optional[int] = 1) -> bool:
    t_range = pd.date_range(
                 '01 Jan 2020', '02 Jan 2020',freq='min')\
                 .strftime('%H:%M').tolist()

    idx = t_range.index(time_value)
    t_range_slice = t_range[idx -M : idx + 1]
    return dataframe.isin(t_range_slice).sum().astype(bool)[0]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time' : ['16:04','16:05']})
get_time_delta_range(df,'16:04')
True

get_time_delta_range(df,'16:09')
False
```

Comment: BTW, May I know what's the role of the class "Optional" here ??

Comment: @PNxZEN don't use `if ...` these are standard python methods which don't apply to `pandas` easily. you can use the `isin` I provided above, Whats your end goal? `Optional` is just that, it just tells you that the argument is optional, it gives the user better and more readable arguments :)

Comment: Thanks, but I got it fixed... Let me show my goal... In a func :
#Check if the current time is mentioned in the Dataframe
    **if df_['Time'].isin(vals).any() == True:**
        _return True_
    **else:**
        _return False_

Any other efficient way to do it ??

Comment: @PNxZEN do you want to show it at a row by row level or if `one` value is in the dataframe just return a single output as `true` ? see my edited function that will return the sum of the true/false values in your dataframe, if there is one, it will return True, if None false.

Comment: @PNxZEN you can indeed, I think you have enough to go with to figure it out:) feel free to open a new question with your own research if you get stuck

Comment: Apologies for the reversed-up question before....  :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are defining your time period, but this will make a range from 25 minutes ago and test each minute in the format you need.

```
current_time = datetime.now()
minutes_prior =  25
start_time = current_time + timedelta(minutes=-minutes_prior))
#pd.date_range(start_time, current_time, freq="1min")

def Time_Check_Min(ttest):
    if ttest in df_.Time.values:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for t in pd.date_range(start_time, current_time, freq="1min"):
    print(t.strftime("%H:%M"))
    #Check if the current time is mentioned in the Dataframe
    Time_Check_Min(t.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

Comment: hi. it is variable in that you can set it to what you want. i just chose 25 minutes. you can use minutes_prior = input('Enter number of minutes to test') or something similar

Comment: Sorry, but the Question change was intended and I got confused ( Don't know why )‍♂️‍♂️